# locating values via input function not working by providing input

Tags: python, pandas, function, input

I am providing Location via input function, but the code is not providing output when i use the variable in data.loc function.

```
  def vehicle_finder(veh_mt,load,loc,partial=[]):
      veh_option = sum(partial)
  
      if veh_option == load:
        combi = list(partial)
        sqft = sum(data.loc[combi]['Sqft'])
        print("Option :", len(combi), "Number of Vehicles", combi, sqft,'Sqft')
        loc = sum(data.loc[combi][location])
        print(loc)
      
      if veh_option >= load:
        return

      for i in range(len(veh_mt)):
        n   = veh_mt[i]
        bal = veh_mt[i+1:]
        vehicle_finder(bal,load,partial+[n]) 

load      = int(input("Enter the total Load : "))
loc     =  input("Enter the Location : ")
vehicle_finder(veh_mt,load,loc)
```

Comment: Can you describe what this function does? specify what is veh_mt and a value, put a value for load and loc (not input). Anyway, if veh_option is never bigger than load you then your function has no return.

Comment: this function bifurcates a given value(load) in possible permutations available from data(Veh_mt) and provides sum of the values associated with the same ie sqft and amount available for those values.    my problem is that i am providing the location from input... but loc variable is not accepting location along with df.loc and giving me output.